# Can't scroll through items in the item battle menu

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Why am I not able to scroll through the items when I pull up the item menu during battle? As you can see in my screenshot, I can only select from these 6 items. I have tried to use the "S" key to scroll down and by clicking on the white down arrow. I also seem to have the same problem in one of the menus, I believe it's in the Facebook messages menu.

[image: Stick of Truth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem occur a few times during my first play-through. I was able to get around it by closing the item menu and re-opening. Sometimes it took several (5 or more) attempts before I could properly scroll through to the item I wanted, but it did eventually work.

Comment: I ended up plugging a controller in and I'm able to scroll though it fine with my left analog stick. I haven't tried your suggestion yet.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me a few times, it always got fixed when using the mouse scroll-wheel if I clicked on any item and used the wheel again (without leaving the item window)

Answer (score 0):

One way that always works for me is the following:

1. Click on any item on the screen (e. g. a Cure Potion)
2. Scroll down with keyboard arrows (not wasd buttons)
3. Click "use item" with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. I guess you need to click somewhere close to bottom on that vertical bar instead of clicking on the arrow.

I also had another problem with scrolling using my laptop's touchpad. But, whenever I switched to mouse, the problem disappeared. I assume it's a driver issue or something.